# Why is this svg code not working

Tags: svg, line, viewbox

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Show Svg</TITLE>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<STYLE>
#viewbox {
    border: 2px solid black;
    }
</STYLE>    

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SVG id="viewbox"  height="400px" width="400px" viewBox="-20 -20 40 40"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
<g id="pic">
<line x="20px" y="0px"  x2="-20px" y2="0px"  
    style="stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);" 
    />
<line x="0"   y="40" x2="0"  y2="-20" 
    style="stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);"  
    />
<rect x="-10" y="-10" width="20" height="20"
    style="stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(255,0,0)"
    /> 
</g>
</SVG>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The debugger shows the lines terminating at x = 0 and
the pic viewbox as 30px x 30px which truncates
the lines to edges of the red box.

So what is happening here?

Comment: All of them I imagine :-)

Comment: You will have a little square into a big square. And on the left & top sides there will be 2 lines that connect those squares. Which is your expectation ?

Comment: I was expecting lines that continued to the opposite borders.

Answer (score 1):

Lines go from x1, y1 to x2, y2 not from x, y to x2, y2. If you correct the attributes it should work.

Note that if you're really writing xhtml (as your namespace suggests) then that is a case sensitive language and all those uppercase tags need to be lowercase.

Comment: Thanks. Next question: why don't x vs x1 and y vs y1 generate errors? I realize that the x and y were just ignored and zero used, but it seems that should generate some sort of error.

Comment: Why should it, you can use attributes that have no meaning to store additional data if you want.

Comment: Also, the SVG specification says that missing line attributes default to 0. It says explicitly they are not an error.